# Reverting back to PHP from HHVM

Tags: php, hhvm

How can I revert back to PHP from HHVM.

I know that moving from php to hhvm you only need to:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php php /usr/bin/hhvm 60
```

How about if I wanted to revert back to php?

```
$ php -v
HipHop VM 3.0.0 (rel)
Compiler: tags/HHVM-3.0.0-0-g59a8db46e4ebf5cfd205fadc12e27a9903fb7aae
Repo schema: 48906efe08d29a403bbe13414f32ccd256708e0b
```

Can is just execute a `ln` command to point to the original php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/update-alternatives.8.html)

```
sudo /usr/bin/update-alternatives --config php
```

Will ask you which version to use.

Comment: It gave me 2 selections, 0, 1 other is hhvm, other is php5. Then choosing php5. running `php-v` still gives hhvm. I believe I used `ln` to replace the php install.

Comment: hhmmmm. Tried both selections, and its both HHVM. Should I reinstall something? php-cli maybe?

Comment: What have you entered to replace the php install ?

Comment: @marcio it was either that alternatives install or an forced symlinked rerouted to the new hhvm.

Comment: If you forced a symmlink on /usr/bin/php i'm afraid you'll have to reinstall php-cli.

Answer (score 0):

For a non-interactive command to set the original php binary as the default, here exemplified with PHP 5:

```
sudo /usr/bin/update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php php /usr/bin/php5 61
```

Note the priority (61) is higher than the priority given to hhvm in your original command.

Answer (score 0):

simply run this command to revert to normal php

```
sudo /usr/share/hhvm/uninstall_fastcgi.sh
```